# How to check if the user leaves the JFrame window?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener

I am writing a program where you can type text. I also added a shortcut system, but I saw something bothering me a bit.

So I created a `JFrame`, that listens to a class extending the `KeyListener` interface.

I created an `ArrayList`, storing the codes of all the keys that are being pressed.

This array list basically functions with the `keyPressed` and `keyReleased` methods. If a key is pressed, then its code goes into the array list. If the key is released, then it quits the array list.
Then I tested a lot this beginning of program, and I noticed that if I leave the frame while pressing any key and then I release the key (not in the frame then) then the program doesn't know that I released the key.

Then how could I either know if the key is still being pressed or not, or know when the user leaves the "attention" on the frame window.

Comment: *"if I leave the frame"* What does that mean? The mouse pointer leaving the frame? The focus leaving the frame? The user getting up and walking outside to enjoy the sunshine? ... For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement [WindowListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) in your **JFrame**

windowActivated event looks like the specific event you need to use.

Answer (score 0):

The `hasFocus()` method of JFrame will return true if the JFrame is in the foreground and false if it isn't. In other words, if the user clicks or otherwise switches outside the JFrame, `hasFocus()` will return false.